# Elements disapear when height is relative

Tags: html, css, height, width

I have 3 `a` with `width:100%`. I don't want to set a height so that the images keep their ratio. For some unknown reason the `a` elements desappear if height is not specified or set to auto. Any idea why this happens?

HTML:

```
<div class="cuerpo">
    <div class="articulosysidebar">
    <!--articulos-->
    <div class="articulos"></div>
  <!--sidebar-->
    <div class="sidebar"></div>
  </div>
<!--botones redes sociales-->
<div class="social">
    <a class="twitter" href="https://twitter.com/franlegon"></a>
    <a class="facebook" href="https://www.facebook.com/franlegon"></a>
    <a class="pinterest" href="http://www.pinterest.com/franlegon/"></a> 
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body{height:2000px}
/**/
.social {
    height:100%;
    width: 4.7%;
}
.social a {
  height: 3vw;            /*HERE I WANT NOTHING*/
  width: 100%;            /*HERE I WANT 100%*/
  float:right;
  display: block;
}

.twitter {background-image: url(http://ow.ly/IPVSe);}
.facebook {background-image: url(http://ow.ly/IPVWg);}
.pinterest {background-image: url(http://ow.ly/IPVGB);}

/**/
.cuerpo {
    width:100%;
    height:100%
}

.articulosysidebar {
    width:91%;
    height:100%;
    background:#DEDEEC;
    margin-right:4%;
    float:right;
}

/**/
.articulos {
    width: 74%;
    height:100%;
    float: left;
}

/**/
.sidebar {
    background: #165eac;
    float:right;
    width: 25%;
    height:100%;

}
```

also available here: **http://jsfiddle.net/FranLegon/y7so6u10/**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because your `a` tag is empty. If you want it to grow with it's content you need to give it some content (`background` is no content). You could add the image you want with an `img` tag inside.

```
<a class="twitter"><img src="url(http://ow.ly/IPVSe)" alt="Twitter /></a>
```

And in your .css file:

```
.social a img {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: This is my recommendation as well. Updated fiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/fqzmn5rd/2/

Comment: @AnthonyTJRivas thanks a lot! but now the `img`s have a blank space (looks like a margin but it isn't) i can't get rid of. Any idea why this happens?

Comment: Hmm. Don't know can you post a fiddle?

Answer (score 1):

Because your link tag is empty `<a></a>`, I suggest you add:

```
<a class="twitter">Twitter</a>
```

And add below code to hide the text:

```
.twitter {
  text-indent: -9999px;
}
```

Updated demo http://jsfiddle.net/y7so6u10/5/